# URL encode with smarty

Tags: smarty

I want to encode an url with smarty.

```
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={$var} " target="_blank"></a>
```

$var contains my datas url

Comment: @user2261430 Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 14):

With [escape modifier](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.escape.tpl) you may set optional escape_type 'url' to return rawurlencode().

```
{$var|escape:'url'}
```

By default {$var|escape} uses escape_type 'html' and returns htmlspecialchars() where '&' (ampersand) becomes `&amp;`. So 'url' might be useful. rawurlencode() protects literal characters from being interpreted as special URL delimiters:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={$var|escape:'url'} " target="_blank"></a>
```

Comment: Hmmm, but do you then also need to escape the thing to html as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the escape modifier

```
{$var|escape}
```

More info at:
http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.escape.tpl

Answer (score 0):

You can also use PHP function urlencode as modifier.

PHP functions can be used as modifiers, [$security](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/variable.security.tpl) permitting.

```
//the "rewind" paramater registers the current location
<a href="{$SCRIPT_NAME}?page=foo&rewind={$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI|urlencode}">click here</a>
```